Tailwindcss Failed to compile because of some css files
I'm currently facing this problem whenever I want to build my application.
Failed to compile.
static/css/main.8da26278.css from CSS Minimizer plugin
\css\main.8da26278.css:1356:42: Unknown word [webpack://./src/index.css:3,0][static/css/main.8da26278.css:1356,42]
I couldn't find anything related to this error. Can you please help?
I tried adding auto-prefixer and postcss config and nothing works..
this is my config file
 /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    content: [
      "./src/*/.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
     ],
  theme: {
       extend: { boxShadow: {
          'cardShadow': 'rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;'
    }, fontFamily: {
          'lama': ['Lama Sans', 'sans-serif']
    }},
  },
     plugins: [],
     screens: {
        lg: { max: "1920px" },
        md: { max: "1000px" }
  },
}


I see you have problem with TailwindCSS and webpack. This error happen because CSS file or config has mistake.
First, check your CSS file around line 1356. Look for typos, missing semicolons, or incorrect syntax. Sometimes simple mistake can break the build.
Your Tailwind config might also have issue. I notice small mistake in content paths. It should look like this:
content: [
  "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
]

Make sure paths are correct, with two asterisks to match all files in subdirectories. Also check your extend section for syntax errors.
If still not work, try deleting node_modules and run npm install again. Sometimes reinstalling dependencies fix weird errors.
